# Avatars grabbed by discord.py bot not loading on mobile

Tags: iphone, discord, discord.py

In every command and embed that i have that uses the avatar_url, the image is not loading on iphone. This includes thumbnails and icons of embeds as well as just the embed image. I have no idea what it is and I've been told that it's a discord issue and that it cannot be fixed but I came here just in case. I asked a few friends on iphone if it was working for them either and it wasn't so it's not just me that my bot's images aren't loading for but it works perfectly on desktop.
Here's my profile picture command code for enlarging profile pictures in case it's something in the code that i'm just not seeing that could affect it in anyway idk.

````
async def pfp(ctx, member : discord.Member = None):
    " :Shows targeted user's avatar/profile picture."
    member = ctx.author if not member else member

    embed = discord.Embed(
    title = f"**{member.name}'s Profile Picture**",
    color = discord.Color.green()
    )
    embed.set_image(url='{}'.format(member.avatar_url))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue except in `discord.js` - try avatar_url() - it fixed mine.
Slightly different syntax so apologies if this is incorrect

Comment: It seems like it is a problem with discord.py rather than discord itself since other libraries work. I'm surprise I didn't notice this, but checked and have same issue.